# Regex to extract digits before word while ignoring certain lines

Tags: python, regex

Using Python and pdf2text I'm trying to extract a postcode from a 4000 odd single page PDF files I have received to print and mail - unfortunately I do not have access to the original files so can't adjust when creating files.

My end goal here is to rename all the PDF files with the Postalcode_ExistingFilename.pdf so I can sort them for the postal network. I'll also need to combine PDF"s for the same customer into one file but that's another problem.

In the PDF we have the word "Dear" and the postal code is before that (albeit a few lines up):

```
04 Jul 2018

Mr Sam Sample
123 Sample Street
Sample Suburb
Sample City 1234

Dear Sam
```

I've managed to get it work with

```
(\d+)\s*Dear
```

until the number of address lines changes which causes the conversion to text to add a block of text between the Dear and postcode.

```
04 Jul 2018

Mr Sam Sample
123 Sample Street
Sample City 1234

PO Box 1234
Sample City
Phone: 01234567
Fax: 01234568
Email: email@email.com
Website: email.com

Dear Sam
```

I tried to get this working from the top and look for the first 4 digit excluding `2018`, however any 4 digit street numbers were being matched which isn't what I'm after.

Any advice you can give would be awesome.

Comment: Try `\b\d{4}\b(?<!2018)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/m4VkRG/1/), which will exclude 2018 from being matched. Are you expecting other years in your files?

Comment: `(\d{4})\n{2}(.+\n)+\nDear` Postal code is in group 1.

Comment: Thanks @pkpkpk for the quick reply. That seems to stumble if the address is also 4 digits i.e. 1920 Sample Street. There is also the possibility of other numbers appearing in the address if looking from top down whereas at least the Dear route is known.

Comment: @joshlindsay is the postcode always at the end of a line, whereas the address isn't? If so try `\b\d{4}$\b(?<!2018)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/m4VkRG/2/)

Comment: @Igle Thanks for the quick reply. That seems to work on the second version but not on the first. Is there a way to combine the two?

Comment: @pkpkpk for the most part yes, I can deal with the few that would not be manually if needed (will write something for them to fail gracefully). That last example didn't seem to work for me. Does it help if the postal code will never be before Line 4 (excl blank lines)?

Comment: @pkpkpk That is correct.

Comment: I got you, try `re.findall(r"\b\d{4}$\b(?<!2018)",str,re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: You've nailed it @pkpkpk. Legend! A few exceptions to deal with manually but totally doable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression:

`\b\d{4}$\b(?<!2018)`

- `\b` Open word boundary.
- `\d{4}$` Match exactly four digits at the end of line.
- `\b`        Close word boundary.
- `(?<!2018)` Negative lookbehind to check that the group of four digits is not 2018.

You can try it live [here](https://regex101.com/r/m4VkRG/3/). The regular expression is based on the assumptions, as per the comments, that the postcode occurs at the end of the line. If you are expecting different years, you can simply adjust the negative lookbehind to deal with additional years. For example:

- `(?<!2018|2017)` will exclude 2017 or 2018.
- `(?<!201[0-9])` will exclude years from 2010 to 2019.

According to your Python version you might need to specify the re.MULTILINE flag for start and end of line assertions.

```
>>> str = """04 Jul 2018

Mr Sam Sample
1235 Sample Street
Sample City 1234

PO Box 1237
Sample City
Phone: 01234567
Fax: 01234568
Email: email@email.com
Website: email.com

Dear Sam"""

>>>re.findall(r"\b\d{4}$\b(?<!2018)",str,re.MULTILINE)
['1234', '1237']
```

Comment: Hi @pkpkpk. Thanks so much for this. I implemented today and it worked to brief however one version of PDF has a space after the postcode. I thought I solved it but where there was no postcode it looked further down the doc and found another 4 digit number. Is there anyway to append the expression to take that into account while still looking for end of line + one space?

Comment: You are welcome. Try this `re.findall(r"(\b\d{4}(?<!2018))\s*$",str,re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to match 4 digit numbers at the end of line, on lines that doesn't contain date (that is line beginning with number)?

```
import re
re.findall(r'^[^\d].*?\s+(\d{4})\s*$', data, re.MULTILINE)
# ['1234']
```

Comment: Ohhh that's close. Until I ran into PO Box 10376 for the address. Is it possible to explicitly state 4 digits?

Comment: Updated.. Should match only 4 digits now